# Pra que serve o comando link em npm?

Tags: react-native, npm

A pergunta é a mesma do título: Pra que serve o comando link em npm?

Alguns módulos do react native solicitam que seja executado o comando `npm link react-native-nome-do-modulo`

E às vezes alguns módulos param de funcionar quando faço isso.

Qual a verdadeira função desse comando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando vc instala um pacote de terceiros no seu projeto é necessário apontar as dependências destes

Para `android`, por exemplo, normalmente estes tem de ser listadas em `android/app/build.gradle` e em `android/settings.gradle` além de indicar o pacote em `android/app/src/main/java/com/<seuprojeto>/MainApplication.java`

Isso tudo é necessário para que na hora que for montar o projeto este consiga encontrar os arquivos necessários para o funcionamento daquele pacote no seu projeto

Porém ao invés de indicar o caminho manualmente era utilizado o comando `npm link ...` para aplicar as dependências automaticamente

Porém hoje este comando não é mais utilizado e foi substituído por **react-native link**

Comment: no caso, basta eu digitar `react-native link pacote` pra ficar tudo ok?

Comment: e se eu usar o comando acima, não preciso mais digitar manualmente nos arquivos do android?

Comment: se vc der apenas `react-native link` ee já ira procurar todas as dependencias

Comment: porém pode dar `react-native link <nomedopacote>` e "linkar" apenas esse

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo se ocorrer tudo certo não precisará digitar manualmente, porém algumas vezes terá que corrigir algumas coisas

Comment: @Mateus não sou do ramo do React native, nem do desenvolvimento mobile, mas a minha resposta se aplica a este caso ?

Comment: @MarceloRafael olhe na verdade nem sei o que acontece dando hoje o `npm link` em um projeto

Answer (score 0):

Meu ambiente:

```
~/pega-usuarios
~/pega-usuarios/index.js       #retorna um array de usuarios
~/pega-usuarios/package.json   #"name":"pega"  #pega será usado para npm link pega.
```

se eu der um `npm link` dentro desta pasta, será criado um link simbolico global em `{prefix}/lib/node_modules/<package>`

Agora estou em meu site e quero pegar essa lista de usuarios

```
~/usuarios
~/usuarios/index.js
~/usuarios/package.json      #
```

dando um `npm link pega`, agora eu tenho o pacote `pega` que está na pasta `~/pega-usuarios/`

Motivo disso, quando voce fizer uma alteração no `~/pega-usuarios` será feita também em `~/usuarios/node_modules/pega`

#### Observações

-Quando voce requere um pacote globalmente linkado, como o caso de `pega`, ele não vai para dependencias em `package.json` ele vai apenas para `node_modules/`

**Fonte**
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link